# jquery append data to html according to order number

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I need to build a list with 6 `li`'s and their values (empty or not) and then append it to an existing `li`.

Having these results in return from an sql query:

```
id_news  title      category  order
-------  --------   --------  -----
3        Alex...    12        1
12415    Obama...   3         3
```

With that data I need to build an in order by `order` list, and by that I mean that the list should be something like:

```
<ul>
    <li data-order="1"> Alex... </li>
    <li data-order="2"> No featured news here, click to add </li>
    <li data-order="3"> Obama... </li>
    <li data-order="4"> No featured news here, click to add </li>
    <li data-order="5"> No featured news here, click to add </li>
    <li data-order="6"> No featured news here, click to add </li>
</ul>
```

So, my questions are:

- Should I have a predefined list and add data there?
- Or, should I do it while building the list? If so, how?

The jQuery code that I have by now:

```
var sublist = '<ul id="order_list"> <h3> Order list: </h3>';
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
  sublist += '<li data-target="'+value['id_news']+'">'+value['headline']+'</li>';
});
sublist += '</ul>';
list.append(sublist);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing is to remember to just get all the markup string text the way you want it before inserting into the DOM, that's going to be 99% of the optimization (not that you aren't, just pointing out that that's definitely the focus to keep).

As for accomplishing that: use the same code you have for creating the markup, but sort your "data" array first. Use javascript arrays' ["sort" function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) for that. [This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ykTgD/) shows it happening.

```
var data = [{order:5}, {order:45}, {order:4}, {order:200}];
data.sort(function(a,b){return a.order-b.order;});

$.each(data,function(index, value){
    document.write(value.order+'<br/>');
});

// output shows the array ordered by the val of the objects' order prop
```

I'm assuming that your data array holds objects with an order property that is numeric. Of course, if the property is named something else then change accordingly, and if it's a string instead of numeric, then use Number() within the function in order for the math to work.

Comment: thanks for the effort, but that's not my question.

Comment: Isn't your question about how to write the data out in a list ordered by its "order" property? You already have code that lists out the markup based on the data, though not sorted propertly, and I told you how to sort it. Per my understanding of the question, put those two things together and that's your answer. If not, can you be a bit more specific?