# Finding li by data-order value and append content

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists, replace

How can I find the `li`'s I need by the value of `data-order`?

The list is contained in:

```
var list = '
    <ul id="order_list"> <h3> Order: </h3>
       <li data-order="1"></li>
       <li data-order="2"></li>
       <li data-order="3"></li>
       <li data-order="4"></li>
       <li data-order="5"></li>
       <li data-order="6"></li>
     </ul>';
```

I have an object named data, which I retrieved with an ajax call. The order value is contained here and this is what I am trying to achieve

```
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
   // append data['title'] between <li ...> </li>
   // where data-order in <li> is data['order']
});
```

So I need to find `li` in `var list` filtered by `data-order` = `data['order']` and append content from `data`;

- Any suggestions?

My other post related to this: [jquery append data to html according to order number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619016/jquery-append-data-to-html-according-to-order-number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: After seeing this post [jquery append data to html according to order number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619016/jquery-append-data-to-html-according-to-order-number)

---

First, take the `h3` out of your `ul`.

Second, make sure your `list` is in the DOM before you start using selectors to manipulate and append data.

Third, don't use line breaks in a string in JS like that. Use concatenation if you need multiple lines:

```
var list = '<h3> Order: </h3>' + 
    '<ul id="order_list">' + 
       '<li data-order="1">No featured news here, click to add</li>' + 
       '<li data-order="2">No featured news here, click to add</li>' + 
       '<li data-order="3">No featured news here, click to add</li>' + 
       '<li data-order="4">No featured news here, click to add</li>' +
       '<li data-order="5">No featured news here, click to add</li>' +
       '<li data-order="6">No featured news here, click to add</li>' +
     '</ul>';

var data = [
    {
        id_news: 3,
        title: 'Alex...',
        category: 12,
        order: 1
    },
    {
        id_news: 12345,
        title: 'Obama...',
        category: 3,
        order: 3
    },
];

$(list).appendTo('body');

$.each(data, function(index, value) {
    $('#order_list li:eq(' + value['order'] + ')').html(value['title']);
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aKcxW/

Comment: thanks @AlienWebguy, but I need to compare it with the existing list in `var list` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619016/jquery-append-data-to-html-according-to-order-number

Comment: If you need to swap out existing `li`s in the position you want, that's even easier: `$('ul#order_list li:eq(' + data['order'] + ')').html(value)`;

Comment: what I'm trying to say it that you are comparing to `$('ul#orderl_list...` which doesn't exists... but is temporally created in `var list`

Comment: I think you're trying too hard to manipulate the date before its in the DOM. I'll make a fiddle quick, hang tight.

Comment: if you have a better idea on how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10619016/jquery-append-data-to-html-according-to-order-number please share :D

Comment: can't get it to work to replace the data... it just won't go. This is my complete jQuery code that I'm currently using: http://jsfiddle.net/MG5mm/

Comment: You need to select JQuery from the left menu. You also need to add an html element in the top box like `<span class="category">click me</span>` because you're trying to bind a click event on an element that does not exist. I also see `$.post('do.php', ..` which won't post correctly from jsfiddle without an absolute URL.

Comment: ignore the `do.php` I just don't understand why `$('#order_list li:eq(' + value['order'] + ')').html(value['title']);` does not work

Comment: Because it's inside the callback of your `$.post` handler which is 404'ing so its not returning any data or even invoking the callback. Like I said, you can't just point it to 'do.php'. Point it to `http://yoursite.com/do.php`